# Matlab plots in loops

Tags: matlab

Can any expert here tell me what is wrong on my code:

```
folderContents=ls;
folderContents(1:2,:)=[];
nFolderContents=size(folderContents,1);    
for i=1:nFolderContents;
        [~, data] = hdrload(folderContents(i,:));
        if size(folderContents(i,:),2)<size(folderContents,2);
        temp=folderContents(i,6:9);
        else
        temp=folderContents(i,6:7);
        end
        temp1(i)=strread(temp);
        w=2*pi*(data([18 35 51 68],1));
        permfreespace=8.854e-12;
        perm=data([18 35 51 68],3);
        cond=perm.*w.*permfreespace;
        conds([18 35 51 68],i)=cond;

       hold all
    end

    figure(4);plot(temp1,conds);
```

the problem is that I want to plot only these lines [18 35 51 68], but I see many lines. `nFolderContents is equal to 31`, when I choose for `i=1:4` I get same problem. why ??

Comment: You should check the size of `temp1` and `conds` to make sure there is no error there.

Comment: the problem is not with matrix dimensions. I can see the plot but there is many lines. I need only four lines as mentioned

Comment: Yes, but you are using the `plot` command with `temp1` and `conds`, so there is a problem there, meaning `temp1` and `conds` don't only contain 4 lines. You also don't need to put a number in `figure()`. Just use `figure()`. Also, add `close all` at the start of your script.

Comment: hi, thank you for your helping. I got the answer  in the answer down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When MATLAB first time executes the line

```
conds([18 35 51 68],i)=cond;
```

it creates an array "conds" with 68 rows and assign the data from 4-element vector "cond" to rows 18,35,51,68 of i-th column of "conds". Rest rows contain zeros. So, I guess, in your code you see 4 lines you are interested in, and 64 lines along X-axis...

To solve your problem it should be enough to replace the mentioned above line by

```
conds(:,i)=cond;
```

Hopefully, I have not missed something ))

Cheers,

//Oleg

Comment: BTW, it is good practice to allocate memory for variables which can be grown in the loop. In you case I would add line "conds = nan(4,nFolderContents);  temp1=nan(1,nFolderContents);" just before the loop.

Comment: yeees, it works now :).... hahaaa thanks a lot. you are the expert one here :) :).. thaaaaaanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can you not just do:

```
plot(temp1([18 35 51 68]),conds([18 35 51 68],:))
```